# What is the probability that these sets intersect?

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-probability

Let $A$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:|x_{1}-x_{n}|+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}|x_{i+1}-x_{i}|\leq d\}$ for a given $d$.  Next, sample a point $p$ uniformly in the unit cube, and let $B$ be the $\ell_1$  ball of fixed radius $r$ about $p$.  Is there a good upper bound for the probability that $A\cap B$ is nonempty, in terms of $n$, $d$, and $r$?  I am most interested in limiting behavior as $n\to\infty$ (in which case, obviously, $d$ and $r$ would have to depend on $n$).

Comment: You seem to use $\ell$ in two different senses...

Comment: Why isn't this the same question as taking $r=0$ and $d=d+r$?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas, if that were the case, then it would also be the same as taking $r=d+r$ and $d=0$.  If we take $d+r=1$ and have $p=(0,1)$, then your set is empty, whereas the new set I just described is not.

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe I meant $d=d+2r$? If I'm right that there's a reformulation like this, it will clearly make your problem much easier.

Answer (score 4):

For $n=3$ this is easy.  A triple is in $A$ iff its maximum and minimum are within $d/2$.  So  $A \cap B_p$ is non-empty iff the maximum and minimum coordinates of $p$ are within $c=\min(1,d/2+2r)$.  This has probability
$$6\left(\int_{x=0}^{1-c}
\int_{y=x}^{x+c}
\int_{z=y}^{x+c}
dz\, dy\, dx
+
\int_{x=1-c}^1
\int_{y=x}^1
\int_{z=y}^1
dz\, dy\, dx
\right)
$$
$$=6\left(\frac{c^2-c^3}{2}+\frac{c^3}{6}\right)=3c^2-2c^3.$$

We'd need other descriptions of $A$ in higher dimensions to make this work for larger $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer. Just wanted to see what your set $A$ looks like in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

---

[image: SolbergSet]

          

<sup>Set $A$ for $d = 0.6$ in origin-centered unit cube.</sup>

---